# Additivity of integration for extended real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Proposition:** Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S}, \mu)$ is a measure space and the functions $f,g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are $\mathcal{S}$-measurable such that $\int |f| d \mu < \infty$ and $\int |g| d \mu < \infty$. Then,
$$\int (f+g) d\mu = \int f d\mu + \int g d\mu.$$

I am wondering if it is possible to generalize the above proposition for extended real valued functions, i.e. can we replace $f,g : X \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f,g : X \to [-\infty, \infty]$? I tried to come up with a counterexample, but I could not do it.

Comment: Yes it is possible (there is no counterexample). However the assumption $\int|f|\,\mathrm d\mu<\infty$ implies that $|f|<\infty$ almost everywhere, i.e., $\mu(\{|f|=\infty\})=0$. (Same story for $g$.)

Comment: Additivity works when $f, g : X \to [0, \infty]$, without any integrability requirement. I'm not sure about $[-\infty, \infty]$ though if we remove the integrability requirement.